# uploaded link from Fog 1.2.0 not working 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

Since I update fog to 1.2.0, I can't access to my upload file with carrierwave.
Images are upload on S3 but i can't asses with url AWSAccessKeyId and signature

url sample:
https://viarezo-upload.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/picture/image/1/TinyGrab_Screen_Shot_22-02-12_12.39.47.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJD6FPWEX5NI3HJ4Q&Signature=8CwjLUPqd1nG7q9s3yo%2BiipzPjw%3D&Expires=1332338050

return code:
SignatureDoesNotMatch

The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

I downgrade fog to 1.1.2 and upload working.

Any idea why fog 1.2 not working